# Disk Utility does not show OK message after Verify Disk

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ssd, disk-utility

Rebooted and Verified Disk twice. There is no OK message and stops here:

[image]

Is it a new behaviour under Mavericks, or something wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: On my Mac Verify Disk I don't see a `Checking extended attributes file`, it just prints `The volume <volume name> appears to be OK` after `Checking catalog hierarchy`. Is "Air" your internal Mac disk? Run in Terminal `sudo fsck_hfs -d -l -n /dev/disk0s2` where `-d`: debug, `-l`: lock filesystem, `-n`: don't repair. Replace `/dev/disk0s2` with the device name associated to "Air" as shown by the `df` command.

Comment: I'm using Mavericks as well and from the moment that I added an SSD to my system, I noticed the same problem but only on the SSD. On the HDD, it stil gives me the feedback "the volume is okay".
Are you using a SSD?

Comment: This bug continues in Mavericks 10.9.3. On my MacBook Pro 15" Retina, the report stops on the item "Checking volume information." for my internal flash-based drive. When used on an external FireWire spinning disk, the report completes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, this is a known bug issue. However, booting to the recovery partition (CMD + R while booting up) or by holding down Option to boot to a USB recovery drive (for those of us with home-brew FusionDrives who haven't gotten around to setting up a Recovery partition again), the process seems to complete without issue.